# Make a fixed node in d3.js un-fixed

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

How can i make d3.js force-layout nodes that have fixed:true become unfixed?

If i set them to d.fixed=false this does not work.

I have code similar to http://bl.ocks.org/norrs/2883411 working. 
So it sets d.fixed=true on drag.

evaluating d.fixed as Boolean doesnt appear to work either.

But i would like to be able to unfix the nodes too.

Either on drag or via some other function.

Im trying this:

```
if (d.fixed==false) {
        d.fixed=true;
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", true);
}
else
{
        d.fixed = false;
        d3.select(this).classed("fixed", false);
}
```

The bad results can be seen on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2u5KB/2/

Thanks,
Gareth.

Comment: Setting `fixed` to `false` should work. Could you post a complete example that illustrates the problem please?

Comment: Try calling force.resume() after you change the node properties.

Comment: Actually you may need to call [force.start()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-start) instead.

Comment: I just tried a test and didn't need to call resume or start to unfix a node. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2u5KB/1/ (see dragend function). Setting the node's fixed property to false is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i have updated my question with a example of whats going wrong for me.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do -- set a class when a node is dragged? http://jsfiddle.net/2u5KB/3/

Comment: Lars, i wanted to be able to fix and then unfix nodes on drag. Ive updated your jsfiddle to show this working: http://jsfiddle.net/2u5KB/4/

Comment: So does that jsfiddle do what you want now? Note that the default force drag behaviour already sets `fixed` when you start dragging and unsets it when finished dragging.

Comment: yea it works the way i wanted now. thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

OK i worked out my problem.

I was doing the check and change on d.fixed in the **dragstart** method.

Moving the code to the **dragend** method resolved the problem.

I guess dragstart has some different behavior that i expected